# How many students would have to take the exam to ensure with probability at least $.9$ that the class average would be within $5$ of $75$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

I'm having trouble solving this problem:

> From past experience, a professor knows that the test score of a
>    student taking her final examination is a random variable with mean
>    $75$.
>   How many students would have to take the examination to ensure with
>    probability at least $.9$ that the class average would be within $5$ of
>    $75$? Use the central limit theorem.
>
> The professor knows that the variance of a student's test score is $25$.

I'm not entirely sure on how to solve this problem.

Right now this is what I have:

We know: $\mu = 75$ and $\sigma^2 = 25$.

This is what I set up (by defn C.L.T): $\mathbb{P}(\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n - n75}{5\sqrt{n}}\le\frac{.9-n75}{5\sqrt{n}}) = 1-\mathbb{P}(\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n - n75}{5\sqrt{n}}>\frac{.9-n75}{5\sqrt{n}})$

I'm not sure how to solve for $n$. Thanks.

Comment: You're missing some information -- you need to have the variance of the final exam of the students.

Comment: @Batman Just updated

Comment: You want to write the probability that $P(|S_n/n - 75| \le 5) \ge 0.9$ using the information from the CLT; looking cursorily at what you wrote, I think there might be an incorrect substitution.

Comment: This exercise is terrible. To the attention of non probabilist readers, let us mention that it is the logical equivalent of the following: *Consider some real valued sequence $(x_n)$ such that $nx_n\to1$, find some $n$ such that $x_k\leqslant\frac1{10}$ for every $k\geqslant n$*. Scary, no?

Comment: @Did How would the exercise need to be changed?

Comment: @355durch113 Adding some missing independence hypothesis and asking to use Bienaymé-Chebychev instead of CLT would be an option.

Comment: @Did Simulating with MATLAB suggests that the approch below yields a way too high result. [This solution](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241660/number-of-die-rolls-needed-for-average-to-converge-to-roll-expectancy) returns 9503 out of 10000 experiments within the desired range.

Answer (score 1):

If the students have mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then the distribution for the average of $n$ students is approximately normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.

In this case, you want to know the probability that the sample mean $\bar{X}$ is within $\pm r$ of the true mean $\mu$. So, $$P(\mu-r \leq \bar{X} \leq \mu-r) = P(-r \leq \bar{X} -\mu \leq r) = P(\frac{-r}{ \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}} \leq \frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}} \leq  \frac{r}{ \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}} ) \approx P(\frac{-r \sqrt{n}}{\sigma} \leq N(0,1) \leq \frac{r \sqrt{n}}{\sigma})$$ since $\frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}}$ is approximated to be standard normal.

By symmetry of the normal distribution, 
$$P(\frac{-r \sqrt{n}}{\sigma} \leq N(0,1) \leq \frac{r \sqrt{n}}{\sigma}) = 1- 2 Q(\frac{r \sqrt{n}}{\sigma}) = 1-2 \Phi(\frac{-r \sqrt{n}}{\sigma})$$

where $Q$ is the complementary standard normal CDF and $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF.

In this case, you want $0.9=1-2 \Phi(\frac{-r \sqrt{n}}{\sigma})$. You can solve this for $\Phi(\frac{-r \sqrt{n}}{\sigma})=0.05$, look up the value $z$ such that $\Phi(z)=0.05$ and then solve $z=\frac{-r \sqrt{n}}{\sigma}$ for $n$.

Since you have to have an integer number of students, round the resulting $n$ up (which will give you a higher probability of being within the interval than $0.9$ if it is not an integer).

Comment: "since $\frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}}$ is standard normal" IS IT? In fact, nothing in the hypotheses implies that.

Comment: @Did I agree with you that it isn't. Statisticians always assume everything is approximately normal, even when they shouldn't -- my guess would be that the problem is assuming the same fallacy.

Comment: "since $\frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}}$ is approximated to be standard normal" Approximated how? This is the whole point, which makes the question a terrible exercise.

Comment: Its probably a high school stat problem, not some precise problem for a mathematical statistics class.

Comment: Let me follow you and let us assume this is not a maths question. Then, since it falsely masquerades as one, our urgent task as mathematicians should be to explain why this is not mathematics, instead of supporting the belief that it is. No?

Comment: "the distribution for the average of $n$ students is approximately normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$. " Again, why is that? For which $n$, with an error of size what? And what does that mean to be approximately normal with a variance depending on $n$?

Comment: @Batman, College Probability course