# What is the analytical expression which shows the convergence of a 6 sided fair dice's expected value to 3.5 as a function of the number of rolls(N)?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, characteristic-functions, central-limit-theorem

What is the analytical expression which shows the convergence of a 6 sided fair dice's expected value to 3.5 as a function of the number of rolls(N)?  I realize that there may be a need for a confidence interval.

Here is how to apply the central limit theorem as an approximation for large N rolls. The distribution of the sample mean multiplied by N−−√ is, thanks to the Central Limit Theorem, approximately normal with mean of the population μ and standard deviation σ. So the distribution of the mean (or the sum) is approximately normal for large N with mean μ (or Nμ ) and standard deviation σ/N−−√ (or σN−−√) .

The Central limit theorem can be demonstrated with characteristic functions. That for a discrete uniform distribution such as a 6-sided die is at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Central Limit Theorem is an asymptotic result. I am not sure that it is what you are looking for. I imagine you are looking for some finite sample result. I will present one possible way of doing it.

Let $X_i$ be a random variable taking values in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, which denotes the output of the the $i^{th}$ trial. Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, then by applying Chebyshev's inequality (and noting that $var(S_n)=n \times var(X_1)$, since $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d.), we have

$P(|\frac{S_n}{n}-\mu| > \epsilon) \leq \frac{1}{n\epsilon^2}var(X_1)$

Thus for large value of $n$, this probability goes to zero for any $\epsilon >0$. It is possible to get much tighter results than this by using better concentration inequalities.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. Whatever happened to the characteristic functions which I studied at Northeastern University?

Comment: Now I understand your elegant use of Chebyshev's inequality . However, I was looking for an analytical expression which can be plotted with Python showing the changing value of the fair dice's expected value as the number of dice throws grows to 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 50000? Would you know how to find that? Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure about the question. Suppose you fix $\epsilon =0.2$. Then the above expression gives you a lower bound on the probability that the mean $S_n/n$ lies in the interval $[3.3,3.7]$. This probability increases to 1 as $1-c/n$, and you can plot it. Is it what you were looking for?

Comment: May I ask what c in 1 - c/n? Thank you.

Comment: It is $var(X_1)/\epsilon^2$ from the expression we got by using Chebychev's inequality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is n? What is var(X1)? Your answer makes sense to me?

Comment: $n$ is the number of samples, or the number of independent throws of a fair dice. $X_i$ is the variable that represents the output of the $i^{th}$ throw, and $var(X_1)$ is the variance of this random variable, i.e., $var(x_1) = \mathbb{E}(X_1 - \mathbb{E}X_1)^2$, which is equal to 35/12 in the case of a fair die.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just accepted your answer. Are you a mathematician?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45628/discussion-between-panini-and-frank).